# httpd substitute not able to use (environment) variables (request dependent)

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, substitution, apache2.4

I have a question about substitution. 
I'm trying todo the following substitution using the following line:

> Substitute "s|http://localhost:81|%{HOST}/subpart|i"

but %{HOST} is not replaced with the current host of the request.

PS: using apache 2.4

Context: I'm trying to use apache as a reverse proxy and forward a request to another server. On the returned HTML I would like to execute the substition using as a replacement value the actual HOST used by the original client request (http://host/...)

Answer (score 3):

Support for expressions (and thereby access to variables) was added to mod_substitute in 2.5.1.
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_substitute.html

Answer (score 0):

Variables are not accepted there at all. Use something like mod_proxy_html.